# ModelForms and Multiple Datasbase - error in form.is_valid()

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hi,

I just have multiple database in my django website.. each user use a different database, setted in UserProfile.

My problem is:

How can I set the modelForm to use the specific database?

I got these error:  table XX doesn't exists. because django is try to use my auth db.. I try tu use router, but all samples I found in internet, doesn't use database name from UserProfile.

Here is my Form:

```python
class ClienteForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Pessoa

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        vUserProfile = kwargs.pop('vUserProfile', None)
        super(ClienteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here my traceback:

```python
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cadastro/pessoa/novo/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django_evolution',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'pagination',
 'bootstrap_toolkit',
 'web_core')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/fellipeh/PycharmProjects/webconflex/cadastros/views.py" in EditaPessoa
  47.             if formPessoa.is_valid():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  126.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  117.             self.full_clean()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  274.         self._post_clean()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  344.             self.validate_unique()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in validate_unique
  353.             self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in validate_unique
  731.         errors = self._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _perform_unique_checks
  826.             if qs.exists():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in exists
  596.             return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in has_results
  442.         return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/firebird/base.py" in execute
  158.             six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*self.error_info(e, query, params)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/firebird/base.py" in execute
  150.             return self.cursor.execute(q, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py" in execute
  3322.                                     PreparedStatement(operation, self, True))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py" in __init__
  1934.                 "Error while preparing SQL statement:")

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /cadastro/pessoa/novo/
Exception Value: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -204\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -204\n- Table unknown\n- PESSOA\n- At line 1, column 41', u'-204 -- SELECT FIRST 1 (1) AS "A" FROM "PESSOA" WHERE "PESSOA"."IDPESSOA" = -1')
```

Here is my Pessoa model:

```python
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    idsys_point_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=28, primary_key=True)
    idpessoa = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Código', primary_key=True, default=-1)
    data_cadastro = models.DateTimeField(u'Data/Hora Cadastro', default=datetime.now, blank=True, editable=False)
    data_atualizacao = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=u'Data/Hora da Última Atualização', default=datetime.now,
                                        blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Status',
                          max_length=1,
                          default='A',
                          choices=Ativo_Inativo_CHOICE)
    razao_social = models.CharField(u'Razão Social *', max_length=70, null=False)
    nome_fantasia = models.CharField(u'Nome Fantasia', max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
    endereco = models.CharField(u'Endereço *', max_length=150, null=False)
    numero = models.CharField(u'Número *', max_length=30, null=False)
    bairro = models.CharField(u'Bairro *', max_length=40, null=False)
    complemento = models.CharField(u'Complemento', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    idcidade = models.ForeignKey('web_core.Cidade', verbose_name="Cidade *",
                             db_column='idcidade', null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(u'E-Mail', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    fisico_juridico = models.CharField('Tipo Cadastro *',
                                   max_length=1,
                                   default='F',
                                   choices=FIS_JUR_CHOICE)
    fis_cpf = models.CharField(u'CPF', max_length=14, null=True, blank=True)
    jur_cnpj = models.CharField(u'CNPJ', max_length=18, null=True, blank=True)
    telefone1 = models.CharField(u'Telefone', max_length=14)
    idrepresentante = models.IntegerField(u'Representante', null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['razao_social']
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pessoa'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.razao_social
```

Comment: The key is to use custom auth backend, that will recieve user data and decide, what database will you use. You can find example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Comment: can you send example? How can i use custom auth backend to set is_valid?

Comment: Oh sorry for misunderstanding. Auth backend is user authentication. It is next step if you will use authentication. May be you need to describe validation process in your custom user model.

Comment: could you post your `Pessoa` model code? the error is that table is missing.

Comment: @Hieu Nguyen : I edited my post, and added Pessoa model.. @m9_psy : I don`t have custom model validation,I just add 3 new fields to the UserProfile, only thins.

Comment: @Hieu Nguyen : the problem is.. table Pessoa doesn't exists in default database, only in my other databse, but .is_valid try to get this table in default database.. my question is: how can I force .is_valid get data from other database?

Comment: I think the source of all your problems is: `each user use a different database` - why do you have this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply my own question...

The only way to get this right is make one middleware to get database name and work with locals, like this:

File: middleware.py

```
from threading import local
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from web_core.models import UserProfile

my_local_global = local()


class CustomerMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        my_local_global.database_name = get_database_name(request)


def get_database_name(request):
    session_key = request.session.session_key
    try:
        session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
        uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)

        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=uid)

        if profile:
            return profile.dbname
        else:
            return None
    except:
        return None
```

after this, add **middleware.py** in your **settings.py**:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
(..)
    'middleware.CustomerMiddleware',
)
```

to finish, make one more file to get db router:

File: authrouter:

```
class PadraoRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        from middleware import my_local_global
        return my_local_global.database_name

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        from middleware import my_local_global
        return my_local_global.database_name

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return True


class AuthRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'sessions':
            return 'auth_db'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'web_core':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'sessions':
            return 'auth_db'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'web_core':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or\
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return True
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'sessions' or\
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'sessions':
            return True
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'web_core' or\
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'web_core':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'auth_db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'auth'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return False
        return None
```

NOTE: I need to put **import** in each def, because Django 1.5.1 has a bug, if you put import into top of file.. cycle imports..

after this, change again your **settings.py** to add the router:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['authrouter.AuthRouter',
                    'authrouter.PadraoRouter']
```

**Remember**

I make this way, because I have one database, only for auth.. each user can access a different database, depending what is save in dbname field.

If you have other solution, please let's me know!

Thanks to everybody.